# Tesseract - Detecting small font size of image and convert to text

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I have a screenshot of the bank cheque, I need all the text from this screenshot but tesseract is unable to read it properly. I also tried to pre-process the image but the output fails miserably.

I am using ImageMagick for pre-processing and Tesseract for recognizing text.
The link to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNNhS.jpg

I am able to retrieve the account number, but not IFSC code and person name "SRINIVAS"

The steps I am following is as follows:

```
magick -density 300 check1.jpg -depth 8 -strip -background white -alpha off check1.png

magick convert check1.png -resize 250% res_check1.png

convert -brightness-contrast 10x30 res_check1.png b_res_check1.png

convert b_res_check1.png -threshold 45% bin_res_check1.png

tesseract bin_res_check1.png o_res_check1
```

Note: I tried to resize the image upto 400% but it did not work.
Google Vision API is able to read and convert every single text properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you can use -lat (local area threshold) to process the image to clean the background. I also have a bash shell script, text cleaner, at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php.

Input:

[image]

For ImageMagick 6, try

```
convert input.jpg -negate -lat 25x25+10% -negate result.png
```

Vary the -lat arguments to see if you can improve the results.

For ImageMagick 7, replace convert with magick.

[image]

Does that help? Small fonts are going to be hard to process. Enlarging a raster image, does not usually help much. But you can try with sharpening filters or sharper resize filters, such as -filter catrom. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/

You can also try doing a perspective transformation to rectify the original image before further processing. This might also help. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective

Comment: Sure I will give it a try. The problem is that I need to process thousands of cheques and quality, clarity, brightness, font of every cheque is different. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: I do not have a universal solution apart from the -lat. Too small fonts are always going to be an issue, unless you have a vector image that can scale with density. Raster images are fixed and enlarging will not help much.